# Failed to archieve Gitolite (Git) and nginx webserver access webspace at the same time

Tags: linux, git, nginx, permissions, gitolite

---

**Starting point:**

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Gitolite (/home/git/)
- Webspace /var/www/webspace (usually owned by www-data:www-data)
- Git user (in www-data group and also tried without beeing in group)

I want to update the webspace as git user with post-receive to a www-data directory. I had it archived before I installed Gitolite, but it doesn't seem to work the same way as it did before (or I am missing something). To make it clear: post-receive is executed after pushing (which it's normally not on Gitolite) ... was a hard time too to archive that.

**Edit: To make it clear: I want to archive that Git and www-data can access and modify the same files.**

---

**What Ive tried:**

- chmod 777 -R /var/www/webspace (after this git can access but nginx returns with 403?)
- Adding Git-User to www-data group
- chown www-data:git -R /var/www/webspace
- chown git:www-data -R /var/www/webspace
- chown git:git -R /var/www/webspace
- chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/webspace (with and without git inside group)(with and without 777)
- Executing post-receive manually (Operation not permitted)
- Executing post-receive manually as root (well ... works of course, but thats not the point)
- ... maybe also some steps more which Im maybe missing rn

---

What Ive noticed so far:

- On the contrary to Git, Gitolite checks the repo out with -rw------ (If i remember correctly), maybe that is why its not working with gitolite but with Git

---

The code (not that it would be important, but just to list everything):

- post-receive

```
    #!/bin/sh
    GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/webspace git checkout -f
```

---

Maybe Im just missing something, but please help me.

Comment: In your post-receive, add the command:
`id > /tmp/id.txt`
Then you will see the user and group id of the process in the output file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add user (git in my case) to group of webspace (www-data for me)

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data git
```

If you were logged in as user logout to  reload the group.

```
logout
#or
exit
#or
CTRL+A+D
```

(If you want to recheck the group login as this user and type "groups" to see the groups the user is in)

---

Make sure the webspace is owned by the correct group. For me:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/webspace
```

(If you want to recheck this you can go in the directory and type "ls -g")

---

In my case I had to modify my "post-receive" a bit,  because the permissions were always -rw----- after checking out, so here is my "post-receive":

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/webspace git checkout -f    #default line to checkout
chmod -R a+r /var/www/webspace     #added by me because of permission issues
```

---

For convenience I had my "post-receive" in the repo directory (/home/git/repositories/repo/hooks/post-receive). The docs tell you to create a new folder (/home/git/local/specific-hooks/repo/post-receive  (but they tell to name it on your own))

*All paths, names, groups and permissions written above only apply to me. They may differ for you installation.

---

**What really solved my problem:**

- Logout after you change groups
- Change permission (chmod) in post-receive

Answer (score 1):

Try and follow "[adding other (non-update) hooks](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/cookbook#adding-other-non-update-hooks)" in order for Gitolite to call the relevant post-receive hook.

1. add this line in the `rc` file, within the `%RC` block, if it's not already present, or uncomment it if it's already present and commented out:

   ```
   LOCAL_CODE => "$ENV{HOME}/local",
   ```
2. put your hooks into that directory, in a sub-sub-directory called "hooks/common":

   ```sh
   # log on to gitolite hosting user on the server, then:
   cd $HOME
   mkdir -p local/hooks/common
   cp your-post-receive-hook local/hooks/common/post-receive
   chmod +x local/hooks/common/post-receive
   ```
3. run `gitolite setup` to have the hooks propagate to existing repos (repos created after this will get them anyway).

Comment: I am sorry, but I think you missunderstood. The post-receive works perfectly fine. As I wrote -> "To make it clear: post-receive is executed after pushing (which it's normaly not on Gitolite) ... was a hard time too to archieve that."

Comment: My problem is to let git and www-data read and write the same files.

Comment: @justsomexanda the post-receive should not work, not unless you bypass gitolite completely. My answer is about registering the post-receive in the contexte of Gitolite.

Comment: I followed the instructions on Gitolite-Doc to get post-receive running via specific-hooks. Not really the answer Im looking for. Post-receive is working.